# Numpy maximum argument item number between three columns with output as array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to formulate an array which is the maximum (item # not value) between 3 columns.

E.g.

```
In:  arr=([(1,2,3,4), (4,5,16,0), (7,8,9,2)]) # maximum of columns 0, 1, 2, 3
Out: array([2,2,1,0])  # As: 7 > 4 > 1, 8 > 5 > 2, 16 > 9 > 3, and 4 > 2 > 0
```

Current (non-working solution):

```
np.argmax([arr['f0'], arr['f1'], arr['f2']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `axis` key in `numpy.argmax`, which operates over a specified axis of a `numpy` array independently.  In your case, you want to operate over each column individually by finding the index of the maximum of each column, so specify `axis=0`.  Here's a sample run given your data in IPython:

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: arr=np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,16), (7,8,9)])

In [12]: np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
Out[12]: array([2, 2, 1])
```

The above example was what you had before you edited your post.  With your new data in your edit, here's a sample run:

```
In [13]: arr=np.array([(1,2,3,4), (4,5,16,0), (7,8,9,2)])

In [14]: np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
Out[14]: array([2, 2, 1, 0])
```

More information about `numpy.argmax` can be found here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html